# Keeping islamic words, photos, quran application on mobile

Tags: quran

Assalamu alaikum.. Some of my friends told that, keeping islamic application, messages in mobile is Gunah (not to keep) is this true?

Comment: Well as you can read the Qur'an from any device as i explained here http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/24815/can-we-complete-quran-by-reading-from-book-and-then-from-device/26140#26140 there is no harm of having words/photos etc. on a mobile!

Answer (score -2):

It is okay tO keep the quran in Your phone,but it Will be half useful,it is extremely recomendded tO keep the real quran

Comment: Please read http://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer