# Does one need to perform ablution before handling a Quran on a smartphone?

Tags: quran, wudu

It seems to be generally accepted that you cannot touch the Quran without ablution. What about a copy of the Quran on the smartphone?

Comment: This is basically covered here https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/24815/can-we-complete-quran-by-reading-from-book-and-then-from-device/26140#26140

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The generally-accepted view is that one can only touch a [mus'haf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mus%27haf) (manuscript of the Qur'an) with ablution (free from minor and major impurities). When it comes to touching a smartphone when the mus'haf is on display, it is a matter of *ijtihād* where scholars differ in opinion. It is unlikely that there will be a definite answer on this topic.

[Abdul-Rahman al-Barrak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abdul-Rahman_al-Barrak), a Saudi Salafi cleric, is of the view (see his [fatwa](http://albarrak.islamlight.net/index.php?option=com_ftawa&task=view&id=6491), Arabic only) that it is permitted to recite the Qur'an from a smartphone without ablution since the requirement to be free from impurities apply only to touching a manuscript without a barrier. [Saleh Al-Fawzan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saleh_Al-Fawzan), an Islamic scholar and a member of the Council of Senior Scholars, shares the same view that it is permitted.

['Abdul-Karim Al-Khudair](https://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D8%B9%D8%A8%D8%AF_%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%83%D8%B1%D9%8A%D9%85_%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AE%D8%B6%D9%8A%D8%B1), a mufti and scholar and a member of the Council of Senior Scholars, is of the view that it is not permitted to read from a smart device without ablution. [Muhammad Al-Munajjid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muhammad_Al-Munajjid), an Islamic scholar and the founder and supervisor of the website Islam Q&A, also ruled that ablution is a requirement (although you will find other views on [Islam Q&A](https://islamqa.info/ar/106961) that says it is permissible).